# Django mail not sending the email in proper format?

Tags: python, django

I want to send the email from the Django framework to the user.

I design the following script. when I run this script on the local system on python ide it is sending the mail to a user with SUBJECT  and message body.

But same code is not working in the django framework. it is not sending SUBJECT  and the message body it is sending only last line of the massage.

```
import sys
import calendar
import smtplib 
import shutil
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector
from string import Template

import smtplib

sender = 'mywebsite@organization.com'
receivers = ['employeemail@organization.com']

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
            To: To Person <myemail@organization.com>
            Subject: Virus arm attack on SMTP e-mail test
This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('email.organization.com')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
    print("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
    print("Error: unable to send email")
```

**EXPECTED RESULT** which is getting when email sends from the local system.

**Subject Showing as :** *SMTP e-mail test* 
**Massage body showing as:** This is a test e-mail message. 
 Thanks

**Actual RESULT when mail sends from Django framework** 
*subject is missing and message body printing only Thanks

**Massage body showing as:** 
 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use Django's [mailing system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/). It uses the `smtplib` but will save you the headache of handling the specifics.
Just add the basic settings in `settings.py`

```
# SMTP Host settings
EMAIL_HOST = ''
EMAIL_PORT = ''

# if your SMTP host needs authentication
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''

# Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST and
# EMAIL_PORT settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD settings, if
# set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS and
# EMAIL_USE_SSL settings control whether a secure connection is used.
```

and you are good to go.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
)
```

Comment: It also makes it way easier to mock/debug things (you can e.g. have your dev environment send email to the console / debug log vs going through SMTP)